# Dynamic show/hide of data fields in adminhtml form [magento 1.9]

Tags: magento-1.9

I am implementing one module. 
I have form fields like

```
 $fieldset->addField(
            'date_enabled', 'select', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('slider')->__('Use Date Range'),
                'name'      => 'date_enabled',
                'values'    => array(
                    0 => Mage::helper('slider')->__('No'),
                    1 => Mage::helper('slider')->__('Yes'),
                ),
            )
        );

  $fieldset->addField(
            'from_date', 'date', array(
                'name' => 'from_date',
                'label' => Mage::helper('slider')->__('From Date & Time'),
                'title' => Mage::helper('slider')->__('From Date & Time'),
                'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
                'class' => 'validate-date',
                'time' => true,
                'input_format' => Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
                'format' => $dateFormatIso
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'to_date', 'date', array(
                'name' => 'to_date',
                'label' => Mage::helper('slider')->__('To Date & Time'),
                'title' => Mage::helper('slider')->__('To Date & Time'),
                'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
                'class' => 'validate-date',
                'time' => true,
                'input_format' => Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
                'format' => $dateFormatIso,
                'note'      =>$note,
            )
        );
```

what I want to do is if I select yes from 'Use Date Range'

Then only we can see fields 'From Date & Time' and 'To Date & Time'
Otherwise, those fields are hidden.

How to do that in Magento 1.9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create Dependancy between these two fields.

for that add following code into your form

```
$this->setChild('form_after', $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
            ->addFieldMap('date_enabled','date_enabled')
            ->addFieldMap('from_date','from_date')
            ->addFieldMap('to_date','to_date')
            ->addFieldDependence('from_date','date_enabled',1)
            ->addFieldDependence('to_date','date_enabled',1)

              );
```

This works. And don't need to add javascript for that.